# How can I decode special characters in a parameter in a URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encoding, special-characters, decoding

I am designing a web app that allows a user to authenticate through a redirect URL that contains a token. The token is already generates, what is left is getting the token from the URL and then comparing it with a saved one.

I tried 2 methods:

1. I tried to use decodeURIComponent()

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
...
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { checkToken } from '../helper/token';

function ConfirmationPage(props) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [savedToken, setSavedToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const paramsToken = decodeURIComponent(searchParams.get('token'));
        setToken(paramsToken);

    console.log('Params Token: ', paramsToken);
    console.log('State Token: ', token);

    const userToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
    setSavedToken(userToken.token);

    console.log('User Token: ', userToken.token);
  }, [location.search, token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token && savedToken) {
      checkToken(token, savedToken);
    }
  }, [savedToken, token]);

  return (
    <>
      <LogoNavbar />
      <div className="vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <NormalSpinner size="lg" />
        <p>Token: {token.toString()}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ConfirmationPage;
```

2. I tried to use .replace()

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
...
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { checkToken } from '../helper/token';

function ConfirmationPage(props) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [savedToken, setSavedToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const paramsToken = searchParams.get('token');
    const decodedParamsToken = paramsToken.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');
    setToken(decodedParamsToken);

    console.log('Params Token: ', paramsToken);
    console.log('State Token: ', token);

    const userToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
    setSavedToken(userToken.token);

    console.log('User Token: ', userToken.token);
  }, [location.search, token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token && savedToken) {
      checkToken(token, savedToken);
    }
  }, [savedToken, token]);

  return (
    <>
      <LogoNavbar />
      <div className="vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <NormalSpinner size="lg" />
        <p>Token: {token.toString()}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ConfirmationPage;
```

With either of these methods, in any token containing a symbol such as a +, the + is left out and hence the tokens do not match.

How can I go about ensuring that the special characters are properly decoded. Is there a better way to handle this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.